# Multiple date conversions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that contains multiple rows such as the following examples, with two separate object (string) columns such as the following:

```
Date         Time
18 Jun 2022  10:22
18 Jun 2022  10:03
15 Jun 2022  21:34
```

I need to create a new column which has an integer describing the number of seconds since the epoch combining these two columns

I used the strptime in a lambda function to change the Date to a "YYYY-MM-DD" format, where the MM is now a zero led month number such as "06" and not a "Jun", so the new dataframe is like:

```
Date         Time   NewDate
18 Jun 2022  10:22  2022-06-18
18 Jun 2022  10:03  2022-06-18
15 Jun 2022  21:34  2022-06-15
```

where Date and Time are objects but NewDate is DateTime.

I am stuck trying to re-transform the NewDate datetime value to a string with strftime, then concatenate also the Time string and then change this to the final number of seconds since the epoch.

Of course maybe there's a better overall idea/strategy.

Thank for any help.

Comment: "*number of seconds since the epoch*" you mean Unix epoch?

Comment: I need a progressive number to plot a timeseries and rading around I think the easiest is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, yes. Ideally even better would be having the oldest timestamp as 0 and compute the number of seconds from that one :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [create a datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) data type column like

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

df 
          Date   Time            datetime
0  18 Jun 2022  10:22 2022-06-18 10:22:00
1  18 Jun 2022  10:03 2022-06-18 10:03:00
2  15 Jun 2022  21:34 2022-06-15 21:34:00
```

`pandas` datetime uses Unix time internally, but as nanoseconds since the epoch. You can therefore convert to seconds since the Unix epoch like

```py
df['unix'] = df['datetime'].astype('int64')/1e9

df 
          Date   Time            datetime          unix
0  18 Jun 2022  10:22 2022-06-18 10:22:00  1.655548e+09
1  18 Jun 2022  10:03 2022-06-18 10:03:00  1.655547e+09
2  15 Jun 2022  21:34 2022-06-15 21:34:00  1.655329e+09
```

Note that since we did not set a time zone, the 'datetime' will assumed to be UTC.

To get time in seconds relative to the oldest date, you could use

```py
df['unix']-df['unix'].min()

# or if you don't actually need Unix time:
(df['datetime']-df['datetime'].min()).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Wow , so I had no need of the convoluted strptime to change the month from letters to a number. ... WOW :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @RobertAlexander I've linked the docs; there's no way around pd.to_datetime I think ;-) Note that in general there're some caveats depending on your input, e.g. if the day comes first etc. But all working fine here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling on this in a 40 deg Celsius  room, so possibly you've saved my life :)

Comment: @RobertAlexander man, I hope T drops soon at your place! glad I could help